# Do I get billed for EBS PUBLIC snapshots AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I wanted to know if I get billed for AWS EBS PUBLIC snapshots. I see there are thousands of these and I guess it would be a big problem if I was billed for having them. but the weird part is that I get to delete them though I didn't create such snapshots as far as I know. And some of them exist before the account was even created as I assume.

The bottom line is that I don't want to get charged for these. But I don't wish to do any harm by deleting these public snapshots to anyone else.

And what are they BTW?

[image]

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The account that *owns* the AMI / Snapshot will be charged for storage. You can *view* public AMIs, but you won't be charged for their storage (unless they are yours).

An AMI is actually a Snapshot plus additional metadata. Therefore, if you launch from an AMI and then create a Snapshot (or AMI), much of the data is actually contained in the public AMI so you won't need to pay for it. You only pay for blocks that are new/changed. (It can be confusing, but it generally works out well for you!)